# The SELECT statement includes a reserved word or an argument name that is misspelled or missing, or the punctuation is incorrect. help me

Tags: vb.net

```
Dim SelectQry = "SELECT (StockID) as [Stock ID],(ProductCode) as [Product Code],(ProductName) as [Product Name],(Weight) as [Weight] as (StockLevel) as [StockLevel],MaxStockLevel,FROM stock where StockLevel> 0   group by StockID, ProductCode,ProductName,Weight,StockLevel order by ProductName "
Dim SampleSource As New DataSet
Dim TableView As DataView
```

Comment: Get rid of your brackets round each column. You only need an `As` for a column you want to provide a different name for. So you don't need it for an `As [Weight]` for example. You shouldn't have a comma before the `FROM`. I would strongly suggest you look at [ask] and also consider taking the [tour]. From what I can see you've shown no effort in this. I'm not even sure if that's a valid error.

Answer (score 0):

you have missed something.
see this line

`(Weight) as [Weight] as (StockLevel) as [StockLevel],`

May be its like

`(Weight) as [Weight], (StockLevel) as [StockLevel],`

Also you have put extra comma before `FROM`

Please see below the whole updated query:

`"SELECT (StockID) as [Stock ID],(ProductCode) as [Product Code],(ProductName) as [Product Name],(Weight) as [Weight], (StockLevel) as [StockLevel],MaxStockLevel FROM stock where StockLevel> 0   group by StockID, ProductCode,ProductName,Weight,StockLevel order by ProductName "`

Answer (score 0):

to add to @Vinod's answer:

Also, there should NOT be a comma before the FROM clause.

Comment: SHOWIN " Circular reference caused by alias 'StockLevel' in query definition's SELECT list."

Comment: Do you need:  (StockLevel) as [Stock Level]  ... as you have with some other columns ?

Comment: i have last column "TotalStock

Comment: Can you post the full query that you have now ?   It likely is not the same as it was in the original post.

Comment: Dim SelectQry = "SELECT (StockID) as [Stock ID],(ProductCode) as [Product Code],(ProductName) as [Product Name],(Weight) as [Weight], (StockLevel) as [Stock Level],MaxStockLevel FROM stock where StockLevel> 0   group by StockID, ProductCode,ProductName,Weight,Stock order by ProductName "

Comment: I do not see a 'TotalStock' column there, but for the moment, can you remove the comma and MaxStockLevel before the FROM clause and see how that runs ?